# Tweepy pagination KeyError: 0

Tags: pagination, tweepy

I tried using tweepy's pagination based on the code provided in it's documentation:

````
```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler("Consumer Key here", "Consumer Secret here")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, "Tweepy",
                            count=100).items(250):
    print(status.id)
```
````

However, I get the following error:

````
```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16136/3940301818.py in <module>
----> 1 for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, "Tweepy",
      2                             count=100).items(250):
      3     print(status.id)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py in __next__(self)
     84 
     85     def __next__(self):
---> 86         return self.next()
     87 
     88     def next(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\cursor.py in next(self)
    290         self.page_index += 1
    291         self.num_tweets += 1
--> 292         return self.current_page[self.page_index]
    293 
    294     def prev(self):

KeyError: 0
```
````

Can someone explain and rectify the error please?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Is your code exactly that of the example?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of Tweepy `4.8.0`, the AuthHandler syntax has changed.

Update Tweepy:

```
pip install Tweepy -U
```

and the following should work:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuth2AppHandler("Consumer Key here", "Consumer Secret here")
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, "Tweepy",
                            count=100).items(250):
    print(status.id)
```